# Installing newer versions of R in conda env

Tags: r, conda

I'm trying to get the latest version of R (currently v3.5.0) into a conda env. There's no conda package available yet for 3.5.0. Is there a way I can install 3.5 within the conda env alone and without changing the system-installed version?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9529) there is an R 3.5 for anaconda in the pipeline, but without an ETA so far.